# Positioning sub menu directly under the parent list item

Tags: html, css

I have been trying to configure this for the last three days... I have looked up numerous amount of ways to do this and I believe I am now the closest I've ever been.

My main issue is that I cannot seem to get the list items from the sub menu to vertically lay under it's parent item (The Guest Collection) when hovered over.

My second issue is that whenever I hover over any list item on the nav bar, it goes haywire (fixed nav bar?)

When searching on google, I found a couple pieces of code that used a "drop down button" for the parent list item...  I have used links instead of buttons for my nav bar.  Could that be an issue?

If possible, I would like to keep my CSS on an external style sheet.

HTML

```
<div class = "h_menu">
<ul class = "menu">
<li><a href = "main_page.html">Home</a></li>
<li><a href = "orig_fig.html">Original Figurines</a></li>
<li><a href ="villages.html">Villages</a></li>
<li><a href ="guest_collect.html">The Guest Collection</a>
<ul class = sub_menu1>          
    <li><a href ="disney.html">Disney</a></li>
    <li><a href ="seuss.html">Dr. Seuss</a></li>
    <li><a href ="Rudolph.html">Rudolph and Friends</a></li>
    <li><a href ="santa.html">Santa</a></li>
    <li><a href ="oz.html">Wizard of Oz</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
<li><a href ="orna.html">Oranments</a></li>
<li><a href ="sno_bunn.html">Snow Bunnies</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

CSS (external style sheet)

```
/*navbar*/

.h_menu {
display: table;
margin: 0 auto;}

.menu {
list-style-type: none;
margin: 0;
padding: 0
text-align: center;
display: block;
position: relative;}

.menu li {
display: inline-block;
margin-right: 10px;}

.menu a {
display: inline-block;
color: pink;
font-family: 'Homemade Apple', cursive;}

.menu li a:hover {
background: #DDDDEE;
border: 3px solid pink;
border-radius: 16px;
color: #B76E79; 
padding: 8px;
z-index: 1;}    



/*Drop Down Menu*/

.sub_menu1 {
display: none;} /*hide submenu content*/

.menu li:hover ul {
position: relative;
display: block; } /*position dropdown content*/
```

I have taken some classes on web design, but I am still fairly new with everything... Please be easy on me if this is a dumb question...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the CSS changes needed are.

**CSS:**

```
.sub_menu1 li {
  display: block;
}

.menu a {
  display: inline-block;
  color: pink;
  font-family: 'Homemade Apple', cursive;
  border: 3px solid transparent;
  padding: 8px;
}

.menu li:hover ul {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
}
```

The issues are.

Since when hovering over a `a` tag there is a change in size of the `a` tag, my fix for this is to apply the same padding(`padding: 8px;`) and border(`border: 3px solid transparent;`)(but transparent) to the `a` tags as default.

Second is, when hovering you are positioning the `ul` tag as relative, this will mess up the navbar since its adding new elements. The solution will be simply position the element as `absolute`, this is solving your issue as shown in the below snippet.

```css
/*navbar*/

.h_menu {
  display: table;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.menu {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0 text-align: center;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
}

.menu li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 10px;
}

.menu a {
  display: inline-block;
  color: pink;
  font-family: 'Homemade Apple', cursive;
  border: 3px solid transparent;
  padding: 8px;
}

.menu li a:hover {
  background: #DDDDEE;
  border: 3px solid pink;
  border-radius: 16px;
  color: #B76E79;
  padding: 8px;
  z-index: 1;
}


/*Drop Down Menu*/

.sub_menu1 {
  display: none;
}

.sub_menu1 li {
  display: block;
}


/*hide submenu content*/

.menu li:hover ul {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
}


/*position dropdown content*/
```

```html
<div class="h_menu">
  <ul class="menu">
    <li><a href="main_page.html">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="orig_fig.html">Original Figurines</a></li>
    <li><a href="villages.html">Villages</a></li>
    <li><a href="guest_collect.html">The Guest Collection</a>
      <ul class="sub_menu1">
        <li><a href="disney.html">Disney</a></li>
        <li><a href="seuss.html">Dr. Seuss</a></li>
        <li><a href="Rudolph.html">Rudolph and Friends</a></li>
        <li><a href="santa.html">Santa</a></li>
        <li><a href="oz.html">Wizard of Oz</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="orna.html">Oranments</a></li>
    <li><a href="sno_bunn.html">Snow Bunnies</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Ok, I've applied the the changes. The only thing now is that the sub menu list items need to be listed vertically under its parent item...

Comment: @LatoyaEmmer can you check now? You need to add `display:block` for the items under the sub menus

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure how to solve your problem, but i can see you are missing "" on your class sub_menu1

Answer (score 0):

Click fullpage to see what you want.

I rewrite your code, using float other than inline-block, that's ok, I just prefer float.

The key to make this effect is to successfully target the submenu. Here is the `>` operator.

Second pard is  your sub menu item must overlap you top link, because we are using pure css, `hover` is only we have.

```css
/*navbar*/

.clearfix:after {
  content: '';
  display: table;
  clear: both;
  visibility: hidden;
}

.h-menu {
  margin: 0 auto;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  text-align: center;
}

.menu {
  position: relative;
}

.menu li {
  float: left;
}

.menu a {
  display: block;
  color: pink;
  font-family: 'Homemade Apple', cursive;
  padding: 3px 15px;
}

.menu li:hover>a {
  background: #DDDDEE;
  border: 3px solid pink;
  border-radius: 16px;
  color: #B76E79;
}

.sub-menu {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  /* the number is crucial*/
  top: 30px;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1000;
}


/*show the submenu*/

.menu li:hover>.sub-menu {
  display: block;
}


/*keep the submenu*/

.sub-menu:hover {
  display: block;
}

@media (max-width: 800px) {
  .menu li {
    float: none;
  }
  .sub-menu {
    top: 24px
  }
}
```

```html
<!-- hyphen instead of _ for class name  -->
<nav class="h-menu">
  <ul class="menu">
    <li><a href="main_page.html">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="orig_fig.html">Original Figurines</a></li>
    <li><a href="villages.html">Villages</a></li>
    <li><a href="guest_collect.html">The Guest Collection</a>
      <ul class="sub-menu clearfix">
        <li><a href="disney.html">Disney</a></li>
        <li><a href="seuss.html">Dr. Seuss</a></li>
        <li><a href="Rudolph.html">Rudolph and Friends</a></li>
        <li><a href="santa.html">Santa</a></li>
        <li><a href="oz.html">Wizard of Oz</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="orna.html">Oranments</a></li>
    <li><a href="sno_bunn.html">Snow Bunnies</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```